# Traduction de « buttaface » ou « camarón » ?

Tags: anglais, insultes, vulgarité

En anglais « *buttaface* » veut dire que quelqu'un a un beau corps mais un visage qui est moche (tout est beau *sauf* le visage).  Quand je l'ai expliqué à mon ami mexicain, il m'a dit qu'il y a aussi le mot « *camarón* » (crevette) en espagnol qui veut dire la même chose (le corps a un bon goût mais il faut arracher la tête).

Existe-t-il une expression ou un mot équivalent en français ?

Comment: La première phrase se lit « un beau corps mais un visage qui est moche » ?

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks C'est ce que je veux dire.  Je l'ai corrigé merci.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il me semble n'avoir jamais rencontré de terme ayant cette signification en français. Toujours décrit par périphrase.

Comment: J'ai bien peur d'approuver. Est-ce que ça ouvre un concours de néologismes ?

Answer (score 0):

"*Tête de cul*" est une traduction possible. L'expression se dit en français et ça colle assez bien avec le "Butt-a-face" anglais (sans les tirets).

Comment: L'idée de traduction littérale est amusante, et coincide presque avec une expression française, en effet. Aucune connotation de contraste entre le corps et le visage, hélas.

Comment: "*Tête de cul*" est une expression française qui se trouve aussi être une traduction plus ou moins littérale de "buttaface". Pas l'inverse.

Comment: Heu.. oui nous sommes d'accord. Mais ça fait peu de différence : je voulais dire que l'expression française en question ne véhicule pas le même sens. La symétrie est tentante mais... ce sont de faux amis en réalité. Ou peut-être a-t-elle eu ce sens par le passé ? A rechercher.