# Comment traduire « a rule of thumb » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions

J'aime beaucoup cette expression anglaise qui désigne une règle le plus souvent vraie, ou facilement applicable (qui n'a pas de *thumb* ?), à défaut d'être très précise ; mais j'ai bien de la peine à trouver un bon équivalent en français.

- [Wikipédia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_thumb) n'en a pas de version française, et le [Wiktionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rule_of_thumb) joue de la périphrase, tout en indiquant qu'[*as a rule of thumb*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/as_a_rule_of_thumb) se traduit par *en règle générale*. Très bien, mais ce qui m'intéresse, c'est **la** règle en tant que telle.
- [Reverso](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/as%20a%20rule%20of%20thumb) me dit « la règle générale », mais bof — quid s'il y en a plusieurs ? et on a perdu l'idée d'approximation du résultat¹ — idée qu'on retrouve avec *a vue de nez*. Malheureusement, c'est encore une manière plutôt qu'un nom, et je me vois mal donner ma « vue de nez » à quelqu'un pour qu'il résolve en gros son problème.
- [Linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/rule+of+thumb.html) est plus prolixe, *règle approximative*, *empirique*, *pratique*, *d'or*, *(de) l'arbitraire*, *façon* ou *constatation générale*, mais tout ça vient un peu trop d'unesco.gouv.eu, et je cherche quelque chose de plus courant.

*À vue de nez* est très bien, sauf que… **c'est quoi le substantif² qui permet de voir du nez ?**

---

¹ il ne reste que l'approximation sur les cas d'application
<sup><sub>² Si je remets un lien vers la dérivation des termes manquants, ça compte comme de l'abus ?</sub></sup>

Comment: Précisons : dans le cas pour lequel ça m'intéresse le plus, l'idée est que parmi une foule de choix possibles, l'un en particulier est en général le meilleur. Par contre, dans certains cas, ç'en est un autre, et encore plus rarement, un autre, etc. Du coup, dire *en général* se fait bien, mais manque à la fois l'aspect « regarder donc choisir » (ce à quoi sert le *thumb*), et l'aspect « l'erreur n'est pas grande ».

Comment: Dans un contexte philosophique (pré-socratique de préférence), *selon la doxa* pourrait convenir.

Comment: Harraps's donne **méthode empirique**

Comment: [Bonne] Étiquette?

Comment: Alexis: Hmm, non, pas vraiment, on est loin de manières ou d'éthique, on parle plutôt de meilleurs choix et d'efficacité. @cl-r: J'aime bien *doxa*, même si on est pas dans le contexte. (Ça donne un peu l'impression d'utiliser des mots compliqués de façon gratuite, mais au moins ce sont de bons mots compliqués.)

Comment: Je serais tenté de traduire par _la_ _règle_ _l'art_

Comment: @LucM: Si tu as voulu écrire *la règle de l'art*, je ne crois pas que ça soit ce que je veuille dire : ça serait, d'après moi, « la meilleure façon de le faire », alors que ce que je cherche c'est « une façon simple qui donne de bons résultats ».

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks Arrggg Encore la dyslexie...  Oui, c'est bien ce que j'ai voulu dire :-)

Comment: *En gros* semble relativement proche dans le registre courant...

Comment: Qc. uniquement : _à l’œil_. C'est bien l’œil qui voit du nez ;)

Comment: *heuristique*...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Et si on se passait d'adjectif ? La règle, c'est… *la règle* ! Le reste, c'est l'exception, ou bien la marge d'erreur, mais si on peut parler de règles *strictes*, *figées*, ou *universelles*, c'est bien parce que d'autres ne le sont pas, elles.

Autrement dit, on peut traduire « *the rule of thumb is that …* » par « **la règle**, c'est que … », et rajouter les détails ensuite : « **l'exception**, c'est quand … », ou « ce qu'on néglige, c'est … ».

Comment: +1 pour le bon sens de la réponse, avec la possibilité quand même d'ajouter *règle ...générale* pour les quelques cas d'ambiguité.

Comment: J'accepte ma propre réponse parce que c'est ce qui colle le plus à la question [précise](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4531/comment-traduire-a-rule-of-thumb#comment8310_4531) que je me posais, et parce que j'ai du mal à accepter ["c'est vrai, on ne peut pas"](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/4532/1514), tout juste que ça puisse être.

Answer (score 9):

La question est intéressante. C'est vrai que ça manque au français quand on s'est habitué à l'utiliser en anglais.

Mais tu dis *je cherche quelque chose de plus courant.* 
Or vraisemblablement s'il y avait une expression courante pour traduire cet idiome, nous l'aurions déjà. Les remarques que tu as réunies sont déjà assez avancées, et il me semble qu'il faut plutôt chercher sur la voie de la description/périphrase la plus courte possible. Les suggestions de Linguee sont assez bonnes il me semble… non ?

À moins de s'embarquer dans d'ineptes *nasospections* et *nasologies**…

* on est ici sémantiquement proches du *pifomètre*, qui a étrangement pris avec le temps la même signification que *au petit bonheur la chance* (= au hasard), alors que ça s'apparente plus au flair et à l'intuition dans ses connotations (rapport au nez, bien sûr).

Comment: Qu'après ça on ne m'accuse pourtant pas d'être le chantre de l'[aporie](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4500/traduction-de-buttaface-ou-camaron).

Comment: J'aime bien le pifomètre, pour la vue de nez (et je n'y avais pas pensé). Mais ça manque la partie « généralement, c'est vrai » (et à là place, c'est *toujours* **très** approximatif).

Answer (score 7):

Des idées de traductions :

- ***"Généralement"***, ***"en général"*** : le terme "*général*", par opposition aux cas particuliers, traduit bien le côté "non gravé dans le marbre" de la "*rule of thumb*". On a alors la fameuse "*exception qui confirme la règle*" qui est sous-entendue.
- ***"Première approche"***, ***"première vue"***, ***"première approximation"*** : le "*à vue de nez*" montre que l'on voit d'abord quelque chose de global (quand on ne regarde pas plus loin que son nez) puis quelques différences quand on regarde de plus près. On retrouve également dans ces termes le sens que Linguee donne à l'expression "*rule of a thumb*".
- ***"Règle bien connue"*** : expression assez proche de la "*règle générale*" récurrente sur les dictionnaires en ligne et présentant l'avantage d'avoir un pluriel. Je pensais aussi à des mots comme "*tradition*", "*usage*" ou encore "*coutume*" mais on s'éloigne de l'idée.
- ***"Règle non gravée dans le marbre"***, ***"règle non figée"*** : évolutions de la première idée qui me sont venues à l'esprit en la relisant.

Comment: Oh, +1 pour l'exception qui confirme la règle, qui m'avait aussi échappée, alors qu'elle est cruciale, pour moi¹. « En première approche », *qui a l'avantage de se substantiver facilement*, me plaît bien aussi. Ça m'inspire une réponse, tout ça… ¹ Je rajoute des détails sous la question.

Comment: J'aime la troiseme

Answer (score 2):

Même si tu cites *empirique* comme peu courant, je dois dire que je l'entends relativement souvent, et en tous cas assez que pour le considérer comme vocabulaire courant. Je n'ai jamais rencontré quelqu'un qui me demande ce que ça voulait dire (peut-être par peur, cela dit).

Pour la notion "approximative", en plus des pifomètres déjà évoqués, il y a aussi l'expression *[à la (grosse) louche](http://www.linternaute.com/expression/langue-francaise/477/a-la-louche/)*:

- *À ton avis, combien je peux mettre de pommes dans ce seau?*
- *Je dirais une cinquantaine, à la grosse louche.*

Comment: Même problème qu'avec le [pifomètre](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4531/comment-traduire-a-rule-of-thumb/4559#comment8300_4532) : je trouve qu'il manque l'aspect "c'est souvent parfaitement exact", qui [m'importe](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4531/comment-traduire-a-rule-of-thumb/4559#comment8310_4531). Le problème de la règle empirique, c'est qu'il n'y a pas qu'*empirique* qui peut coincer, il y a aussi que ce que ça veut réellement dire, c'est "règle obtenue empiriquement" (et en plus, ça n'est pas exactement que que je veux exprimer).

Answer (score 1):

Il est aussi possible de traduire par: "grosso modo".

Comment: Il y a bien sûr un rapport de sens entre les deux. Le problème, c'est que *grosso modo* a plutôt un usage adverbial, et on cherche à traduire un substantif... comment substantiver *grosso modo*... Une *grosse mode* ?

Answer (score 1):

une ''... règle d'usage'', précise ou grossière, assez près de la ''règle approximative'' et de la ''règle générale'' mais  absolument pas absolue!

Le pouce est aussi une subdivision de la mesure linéaire le ''pied''.  Bref, l'on sent ici une forme de graduation... la règle.

...et qui se souvient du peintre qui mesure, le pouce devant lui, la perspective.

Answer (score 0):

« Au doigt mouillé ». 
C'est rustique, mais efficace pour savoir d'où vient le vent...
S'emploie aussi comme nom : « Le doigt mouillé, c'est une méthode comme une autre pour gagner en Bourse. »
Quant au rapport avec *thumb*, il devient flagrant.

Comment: Intéressant. J'y vois une variante du [pifomètre](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4531/comment-traduire-a-rule-of-thumb/16178#comment8396_4559), est-ce que ça a vraiment la connotation d'une méthode efficace ?

Comment: Oui. Faites un essai par jour de Mistral : le côté sec est bien celui d'où vient le vent. Mais c'est connoté humoristique...

Answer (score -1):

La « règle générale » est effectivement la première traduction qui m'est venue à l'esprit en voyant le sujet. Pour moi, c'est une règle issue d'un consensus, généralement admise. Je ne suis pas sûr que la version anglaise implique plusieurs possibilités, malgré le « a ».

Comment: En anglais, on peut l'utiliser avec plusieurs possibilités, ce que je veux retranscrire en français.

Comment: OK, alors je suis rarement, ou jamais, tombé sur ce sens multiple, ou il m'a échappé. En fait, je comprends le sens de l'expression, mais j'ignore ce que fait le pouce dans l'histoire...